How to automate model training on Azure for Machine Learning Models created with ModelBuilder
We created several Machine Learning Models with Visual Studio Model Builder because it was very easy to use.
Certain types of models (e.g. object detection) can only be trained on Azure to produce a usable result.
I would like to automated the process of training the models when new data is available.
ModelBuilder generates a Training File for me with a Method "RetrainModel". However, i don't know how i can pass this method the necessary configuration to run this job on Azure.
How can i automate the process of model training from my application ? I would like to do basically the same thing Model Builder does when i click the "Start Training" button.
I know, when i train on Azure, a Azure Machine Learning Job is created automatically which then outputs the desired model. When i train a model from scratch using Azure Machine Learning and python, the models created are of type "MLFlow", but i need a model of type "MLNet" or "ONNX" for local consumption from ML.NET. Could anybody point me to the missing bits to connect those two worlds?
